# root command not found

Tags: terminal, osx-mavericks, octopress, github-pages

I'm trying to setup a blog using octopress by following this [guide](http://www.bobinair.com/blog/setup-octopress-on-github-pages-gh-pages-branch). I'm stuck at the step where I do

```
root: /octopress
```

and my terminal shows

```
bash: root:: command not found
```

My echo PATH output

```
/Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin:/Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/bin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be an edit in a file `_config.yml`, not a command:

> **modify `_config.yml`**

```
root: /octopress  #this is important since we intend the blog to be project page, instead of organization page
```

So you must edit that `_config.yml` file to add/modify that line.